# Require whole gem at once

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm working on a simple ruby gem (created with bundler). In the gem, I have the following:

#### lib/mika.rb

```
require "mika/version"
require "mika/bubble"

module Mika
  # Your code goes here...
end
```

#### lib/mika/bubble.rb

```
module Mika
 class Bubble
 end
end
```

I also have a simple ruby app called mika-consumer that uses bundler for dependency management.

#### Gemfile

```
gem 'mika', path: "~/mika"
```

#### consumer.rb

```
require 'mika'

Mika::Bubble.new
```

but this generates the following error:

> uninitialized constant Mika::Bubble (NameError)

However, if I update consumer as below

```
require 'mika/bubble'

Mika::Bubble.new
```

everything works fine. What should I do to get all the classes created in the Mika gem available in my consumer without be forced to require all of them? Ideally I'd like to require the whole gem at once.

Comment: Did you execute `bundle update` after you have `gem 'mika', path: "~/mika"` added to your `Gemfile`? That is an induced error, `require 'mika'` must be enough.

Comment: Yes. I have originally executed ```bundle install``` and just in case tried ```bundle update``` just now and the result is always ```uninitialized constant StatiStica::Mean (NameError)```. Thanks

Comment: Then would you mind to share knowledge about WTF is `StatiStica::Mean`? It was not even mentioned in your original question :)

Comment: Sorry, wrong copy and paste the error is still ```uninitialized constant Mika::Bubble (NameError)```

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but I think you'll need to eventually come with a per-gem custom solution.